# Applying Function to `Seq[B]` in `Seq[Either[A, B]]`

Tags: scala

Given:

```
  def rights[A, B](xs: Seq[Either[A, B]]): Seq[B] =
    xs.flatMap {
      case Right(x) => List(x)
      case Left(_)  => List.empty
    }

  def lefts[A, B](xs: Seq[Either[A, B]]): Seq[A] =
    xs.flatMap {
      case Right(_) => List.empty
      case Left(x)  => List(x)
    }

  def combine[A, B](xs: Seq[A], ys: Seq[B]): Seq[Either[A,B]] = {
    val l: Seq[Either[A, B]] = xs.map(Left[A,B](_))
    val r: Seq[Either[A, B]] = ys.map(Right[A,B](_))
    l ++ r
  }
```

Is there a better way to do the following, i.e. apply `distinct` to the `Right[Int]` in the `Seq[Either[String, Int]]`.

Look to `res1` in the below output as the desired output.

```
scala> val xs: Seq[Either[String, Int]] = List( Left("foo"), Right(42), Right(6), Right(42) )
xs: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo), Right(42), Right(6), Right(42))

scala> val distinct = rights(xs).distinct
distinct: Seq[Int] = List(42, 6)

scala> combine(lefts(xs), distinct)
res1: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo), Right(42), Right(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with @hayden.sikh's answer (the one that preserves order) is that it has a suboptimal complexity, and is especially inefficient if the `Seq` is a `List` (which it is in your REPL session). Appending an element to a list with `:+` has linear complexity. Calling `contains` on a sequence too. So this is O(n^2).

It would be easy to adapt the answer by using a `Set` in the `foldLeft` accumulator, appending with `+:` and reversing the list at the end.
Or, to avoid the complexity and the cost of maintaining an immutable `Set`, simply use a mutable one and a `flatMap`:

```
val seen = mutable.HashSet[Int]()
xs flatMap { case Right(x) => if (seen(x)) None else { seen += x; Some(Right(x)) }  
             case x => Some(x) }
```

Mutability is fine as long as it's kept local, for example as a detail in an algorithm's implementation (most of the algorithms of the Scala standard library use mutability too, including `distinct`!).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about maintaining the order of the elements in the original `List`, I'd just go with the built-in methods and not unwrap the values from the `Either`:

```scala
scala> val xs: Seq[Either[String, Int]] = List(Left("foo"), Right(42), Right(6), Right(42))
xs: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo), Right(42), Right(6), Right(42))

scala> val (rights, lefts) = xs.partition(_.isRight)
rights: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(42), Right(6), Right(42))
lefts: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo))

scala> lefts ++ rights.distinct
res1: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo), Right(42), Right(6))
```

---

If maintaining order does matter, and assuming you'd want to keep the first occurrence, I'd go with a `foldLeft`:

```scala
scala> val xs2: Seq[Either[String, Int]] = Seq(Left("foo"), Right(42), Left("bar"), Right(6), Left("foo"), Right(42), Right(9))
xs2: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo), Right(42), Left(bar), Right(6), Left(foo), Right(42), Right(9))

scala> val (result, _) = xs2.foldLeft((Seq.empty[Either[String, Int]], Set.empty[Int])) { 
  case ((res, seen), l @ Left(_)) =>
    (res :+ l, seen)
  case ((res, seen), r @ Right(value)) if seen.contains(value) =>
    (res, seen)
  case ((res, seen), r @ Right(value)) =>
   (res :+ r, seen + value)
}
result: Seq[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(foo), Right(42), Left(bar), Right(6), Left(foo), Right(9))
```

This keeps track of two values in the iteration, the result `Seq` and a `Set` of seen `Int` values.  On each iteration, we:

- update the result if the current value is a `Left`.
- use the current result if the current value is a `Right` we've already seen.
- update the result and set of seen values if it's a `Right` we haven't already seen.

At the end the set of seen values is discarded through destructing the resulting tuple and only `result` is saved.